# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var line = "<p><strong>" + name + ": </strong>" + message.field_message_body.und[0].value + "</p>";
console.log(line);
console.log(document.getElementById("messages"));

document.getElementById("messages").appendChild(line);
```

> messages exists and it returns

`<div id=messages"></div>`

Nothing appears to be empty, so I'm not sure why this is being thrown.

Does anyone have any idea why it might be throwing this error?

Comment: try `.appendChild(document.createTextnode(line));` instead of `.appendChild(line);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `line` variable you're passing isn't a `Node`, it's a `String`. Try first using

```
var line = document.createElement("p");
line.innerHTML = "<strong>" + name + ": </strong>" + message.field_message_body.und[0].value;
document.getElementById("messages").appendChild(line);
```

Comment: Yep, discovered that at about the time you posted. This works. I'll award you the point when it lets me.

Comment: also make sure that `name` and `message.field_message_body.und[0].value` are sanitized (i.e. make sure it's not vulnerable to XSS)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var line = "<p><strong>" + name + ": </strong>" + message.field_message_body.und[0].value + "</p>";
var msgHTML = document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = msgHTML + line;
```

Comment: I do not recommend this. this will remove state and event listeners.